# Virtual Studio Code and live share

Tags: window

I'm trying to use Virtual Studio Code and the plugin live share.
After I have logged in, I want to open a meeting which results in the following message:

`You are not authorized to share. You have not registered for VSLS.`

I have already registered with Live Share.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you checked their FAQs/Help pages? How long has this been going on?... In general provide more details. It is also possible that you will get downvoted/deleted as the question does not seem very programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial bits for Visual Studio Live Share did not have a good message here. While you have registered, you have likely not been added to a wave of the preview yet yet.

From the extension README:

**Note:** Visual Studio Live Share is currently in a limited, private preview. During the preview period, you will need to be accepted into the program to share but not to join. Anyone may install the extension and join an accepted "host" as a "guest." Sign up now if you are interested in sharing. Acceptances will occur in waves over the preview period and you will be notified once accepted.